# Qt Windows 10 notifications

Tags: windows, qt

I am trying to make use of the Windows 10 notifications system (the ones poping out from the right side panel, available from notifications tray icon) in my Qt 5.13.0 program. I am looking at the Windows extras class: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-index.html but cannot find any API for such thing. Is it even possible somehow in Qt?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://github.com/mohabouje/WinToast (not a Qt API).

Comment: Yes, thats exactly it. It even provides a qt example. Thanks. I gues there is no qt api, since one has to use.msvc compiler for this to work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, try the [System Tray Icon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html) example.

It is not a Windows only API. The QSystemTrayIcon class works in several platforms. In Windows 10, QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage() shows the notification you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but this is not what I was looking for

Comment: Did you compile and execute the example? I guess you didn't

Comment: I did not have too. I specified in the topic body that I was looking for the Windows 10 side notifications, not generic tray notifications.

Comment: The provided example does exactly that when executed in Windows 10: it creates a native toast notification, using the side notifications area. On other platforms, like windows 7 it provides a balloon message. I would try it if I were you.

Comment: You are right actually, the notifications are Windows 10 style. It is actually a better solution, since its cross platform now. I only need to figure out now either the tray icon functionality can be get rid of. Thank you.